# Alternative for long if..else/switch chain in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 var ifChecks = function( i )
 {
     if( i === 23 )
     {
       // implementation
     }
     else if ( i === 300 )
     {
       // implementation
     }
     else if ... 

  }
```

I have this kind of long if else chain (app. 60 checks) in javascript code, this lengthy chain is inefficient as if 60th check comes as input, then it has to unnecessarily go through 59 checks, so I thought to implement like this.

```
 var implobj = { 23 : handleimpl1,
                 300 : handleimpl2,
                 .
                 .
                 .
               }
 var handleImpl = function( i )
 {
    implobj[i]();
 }
```

Is there any other way better than this solution which can be implemented in javascript?

Note: input is not sequential number, otherwise I could have used array instead of object.

Comment: The only thing I would do differently would be to have `implobj` be a parameter.

Comment: A switch case wouldn't make it as efficient as a map.

Comment: What's wrong with the object literal one?

Comment: The problem might be elsewhere : it's unusual to have 60 functions really different depending on integer values.

Comment: Is each implementation significantly different?

Comment: Oh also it's probably a good idea to make sure that there's an entry in the map for the "i" value.

Comment: Your second example using the object literal is the best way. You may consider adding a `getter` property to the literal to handle default cases.

Comment: @Pointy,jbabey Thank you I will use your suggestion.

Comment: @shmiddty no, all are different implementation

Comment: @dystroy I thought rather than having long chains of code, it will be easier to read if they are separate functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use your idea, coded slightly differently like this:

```
var handleImpl = (function() {
    var implobj = {
        23 : handleimpl1,
        300 : handleimpl2,
        // ...
        defaultImpl: someDefaultFn
    }

    return function(i) {
        (implobj[i] || implobj.defaultImpl)();
    };
}());
```

Comment: Initializing object every time when handleImpl is called vs having this object in global scope. which will be better?

Comment: Actually, this does not initialize every time.  The outer function is run once and returns the inner one.  The inner one has access to the implObj which was set up in that first call.  From then on, you simply need to call `handleImpl(i);`.  If you haven't seen immediately invoked function expressions (IIFEs), it's definitely worth looking them up.